# Destructor runtime crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, destructor

My application crashes when trying to reload a view controller that was previously loaded.

In the interface of MySecondViewController, I have a property that is an instance of MyCustomClass:

```
@interface MySecondViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomClass *myClassInstance;

@end
```

When I press Back in the navigation controller and return to MyFirstViewController, and then try to reload MySecondViewController, I get a crash in the dealloc method of MyCustomClass. The stack details the following:

```
0 objc_release
1 -[MyCustomClass .cxx_destruct]
2 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*)
4 object_dispose
5 -[MyCustomClass dealloc]
6 -[MySecondViewController .cxx_destruct]
```

It seems to arise because, elsewhere, I am storing a pointer to MySecondViewController, and the error is being thrown when that pointer tries to reset to the new instance of MySecondViewController.

MyCustomClass looks like this:

```
@interface MyCustomClass () {

int _myInt;

}

@property (readwrite) AUGraph   processingGraph;
@property (readwrite) MusicPlayer player;

@end

@implementation MyCustomClass

@synthesize processingGraph     = _processingGraph;
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong that's causing this crash?

Comment: Where is your crash ?

Comment: Do you have an explicit dealloc method in MyCustomClass?

Comment: Kinda looks like MyCustomClass is being over-released, but I'm not that familiar with ARC stacks.

Comment: Can you provide the code in your dealloc method?

Comment: @Bhargavi, the crash comes in another class, when storing the pointer to MySecondViewController. The code is: m_mySecondViewController = viewController, where 'm_mySecondViewController' is the MySecondViewController* that will be stored, and 'viewController' is the passed in MySecondViewController.

Comment: @HotLicks - I don't have an explicit dealloc method in MyCustomClass. Should I?

Comment: @CoryPowers - As I mentioned to HotLicks, I don't have a dealloc method.